# Visual Studio 2015 Debug output showing "Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.XXX.RemoteDependency"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 and when I opened an old solution I started getting messages like the one below in my debug output:

> "Application Insights Telemetry:
>   {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.XXX.RemoteDependency"...

I thought a NuGet package had been added but I cannot find it. You should be able to edit ApplicationInsights.config and remove this but since the Nuget package is not installed I do not have this file.

```
<TelemetryChannel>
  <DeveloperMode>false</DeveloperMode>
</TelemetryChannel>
```

http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/02/02/developer-mode/

Has anyone else experienced this and had it removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a file called "ApplicationInsights.config" in the root folder of my project with the values below and now the messages are gone. Don't forget to build your project after putting the file there and I also had to restart Visual Studio for the messages to disappear.

```
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <TelemetryChannel>
    <DeveloperMode>false</DeveloperMode>
  </TelemetryChannel>
</ApplicationInsights>
```